# DatagramSocket doesn't work with java but works with javaw

Tags: java, javaw

I have an app that listens a UDP port.

When I execute my app which is packaged in a JAR file with `javaw -jar myjar.jar`, it can receive packets.

Strangely, if i execute it with `java -jar myjar.jar`, it doesn't receive any packets.

My app doesn't use console for anything. Shouldn't these two commands be identical except omitting the console as noted in [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)?

Comment: Could you post a sample code or list your application dependencies and imports?

Comment: How is your firewall setup?  As `java` and `javaw` are different programs they can have different settings in Windows for example.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, thank you, i disabled the firewall and they worked the same. I would accept it as the answer if you post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As java and javaw are different programs they can have different settings in Windows for example.

Windows has different restriction on a per executable basis.